# MongoDb can't use types in jest - declares ... locally, but it is not exported

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, jestjs

I use the mongodb library in TypeScript for a few functions (e.g. lambda functions but that should not matter).

The imports look like that:

```
import { ObjectId, Db, InsertOneResult } from "mongodb";
```

When I import the function in Jest and execute it I always get the error:

```
Module '"../../node_modules/mongodb/mongodb.ts34"' declares 'ObjectId' locally, but it is not exported.
```

I think something is wrong with my jest logic but I am not sure what. The function itself is working.

My jest config looks like that:

```json
const tsPreset = require("ts-jest/jest-preset");

module.exports = {
  ...tsPreset,
  testEnvironment: "node",
  roots: ["<rootDir>/test"],
  testMatch: ["**/*.test.ts"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/types/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/types/$1",
    "^@/lib/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/lib/$1",
    "^@/functions/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/functions/$1",
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be related to [this ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-4092). The current versions of the mongodb node driver are no longer compatible with typescript 3.9.